# Billionaire Astronaut finds a planet that sings and heals him

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, spaceship

I once was given a paperback as a gift in the mid 80s.

The plot was an addicted  billionaire got bored and bought a starship. He discovered a planet where the grass attaches to his body, and in the process heals him and ends his addiction.

Upon returning to Earth, he discovers he is now penniless (the govt took it all for some reason) and he ends up the male conqubine of a female Chinese oligarch. When he finally escapes, he makes his way back to his planet and lives happily ever after.

Comment: It could happen!